# Dart | Is there any way to convert List<int> to int?

Tags: dart

I'd like to convert `List<int>` to `int` like so.

```
List<int> list = [18, 30];
```

Result:

```
int convertedInt = 1830;
```

Is there any way?

Comment: how did you get `1830` ? is it `18*100+30` or is it `18`+`30`=`1830` (as text). Or, in other words, what should happen if the list contains values less than 10 or greater than 99 ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The last one, I just want align those two values horizontally.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good enough to understand what you mean. Can you change ('edit') your question including a values below 10 or above 99 ?

Comment: Sorry too my question wasn't clear. I think you are right. I just should use 18*100+30. Thank you!

Comment: @KodaiTakata that is something which will not work for double digit integers and is less of dynamic

Answer (score 4):

```
void main() {
  List<int> x = [18,30];
  var y = x.join('');                   // Concatenate each element of list
  int z = int.parse(y);                 // Convert that to int
  print(z);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  List<int> list = [18, 30,1,101];
  int convertedInt = 1830;
  String a = '';
  print(list);
  list.forEach((element) => a = a + ((element>99) ? '**' : element.toString().padLeft(2,'0')) );
  print(a);
}
```

output:

```
[18, 30, 1, 101]
183001**
```

Number less than 10 will get a leading zero, and number larger than 99 will be converted to '**', to make clear they do not fit in two positions.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
List<int> list = [18, 30];
var result = BigInt.parse(encode(Uint8List.fromList(list)),radix: 16)

///list to hex string
static String encode(Uint8List? bytes) {
  if (bytes == null) return '';
  var result = StringBuffer();
  for (var i = 0; i < bytes.lengthInBytes; i++) {
    var part = bytes[i];
    result.write('${part < 16 ? '0' : ''}${part.toRadixString(16)}');
  }
  return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: it is a recommended approach share code snippet along with some description in your answer. However, +1 for good code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it here: use the ByteData class in the `dart:typed_data` library.

```
  List<int> intList = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(intList);
  ByteData byteData = ByteData.view(bytes.buffer);
  int result = byteData.getUint32(0, Endian.big);
  print(result);  // Prints: 66051
```